# Create Linear gradient from top to bottom to status bar and toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to add a Linear gradient color to Status Bar and Toolbar.
I am able to add gradient to status bar and toolbar with angle of 0 degree which shows left to right gradient color `(pink on left and purple on right)`. [image: like this]
But I want the gradient flow with angle of 90 degree which is top to bottom or bottom to top `(eg: top pink and bottom purple)`.I tried but I ended up with this and this.Here status bar and toolbar is being separated, I want both status bar and toolbar to have same gradient color with angle of gradient 90 degree [image: this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On KitKat and later you can control the status bar and action bar backgrounds by setting the status bar as translucent and using a full-screen layout with a scrim, while taking care to blend gradients from status bar into action bar.

One caveat is that KitKat uses its own gradient scrim on top of our own and that doesn't appear to be possible to override, but on Lollipop+ there is no such problem.

Here is an example of the working activity on a MarshMallow emulator:

[image: Example output]

And here is the code I used:

res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Popup" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

res/values/colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ff7000e0</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff400080</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ff40aba0</color>
</resources>
```

res/drawable/statusbar_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#ff7000e0"
        android:startColor="#ff8000ff" />
</shape>
```

res/drawable/actionbar_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ff7000e0"
        android:endColor="#ff400080"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/main_activityStatusBarScrim"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/statusbar_bg"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_activityToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/actionbar_bg"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.Popup"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activityFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#ffffffff">

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // make the main layout fill the screen
        Window window = getWindow();
        final int layoutFlags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
        window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(layoutFlags);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);

        // make the status bar translucent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(0x00000000);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            // N.B. on some (most?) KitKat devices the status bar has a pre-defined gradient that
            // cannot be overridden.
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        }

        // inflate main layout and set up action bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_activityToolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        // set the height of the scrim to standard status bar height for this device (normally 26dp)
        View statusBarScrim = findViewById(R.id.main_activityStatusBarScrim);
        int height;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        } else {
            // belt and braces 
            height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 26f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        if (statusBarScrim != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = statusBarScrim.getLayoutParams();
                lp.height = height;
                statusBarScrim.setLayoutParams(lp);
                statusBarScrim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
```

Comment: Working but due to two different gradient xml it is hard to maintain the gradient consistent.

Comment: You can think of the endColor of the status bar scrim gradient and the startColor of the activity bar gradient as if it were the centerColor of a standard gradient. As long as they are the same value, there will be no discontinuity in the gradient overall.

Comment: @AGDownie Could you please take a look a similar question of mine ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537042/how-to-make-toolbar-and-statusbar-color-gradient-from-top-to-bottom

Comment: @Kumza Ion: Exactly the same solution can be used for your application, if you follow the above carefully, paying close attention to the use of full-screen layout with a "scrim" acting as a background to the status bar to provide a gradient effect. You also need to treat the end colour in the status bar background gradient as the start colour in the toolbar background gradient to blend the two together.